# Retrieving only current user's child values from Firebase

Tags: ios, json, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

Edit, update at bottom, still having issues

---

I have my users stored in Firebase like this - each user's values are stored under their uid (`FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid`):

```
"users" : {
    "tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53" : {
      "gender" : "male",
      "handle" : "TestHandle2",
      "name" : "Timothy",
      "profilePicture" : "https://graph.facebook.com/*removed*/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1"
    }
  }
```

Now to get the user's info (to set it to my `User` object to use around the app), I have this function:

```
func getUserInfo() {
    let userRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")

    // How to get specific user (current user only)??
    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let users = snapshot.value as! [String: Dictionary<String, String>]
        for (key, value) in users {
            guard let name = value["name"] else {print("Error getting user name"); return}
            guard let handle = value["handle"] else {print("Error getting user handle"); return}
            guard let gender = value["gender"] else {print("Error getting user gender"); return}
            guard let profilePicture = value["profilePicture"] else {print("Error getting user profilePicture"); return}
            print("\n\nName: \(name)\nHandle: \(handle)\nGender: \(gender)\nProfile Picture: \(profilePicture)\n\n")
        }
    })
}
```

However this returns the values for all the users in the DB - I only want to get the values for the current user.

What can I add/change to this function to ensure that it only retrieves the values for the current user, and not all users? Also (I can make a separate question if necessary but it seems to be relevant here), is this structure of storing each user's values as children of their UID a good way to do it? I noticed a lot of the time in other examples that they are stored under a `childByAutoId` instead. I'm not sure what advantage that would have.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

If I add another child (uid) to the end of the reference and then cast as a `[String : AnyObject]` dictionary, I can get the current users values, but parsing it seems to be an issue.

```
func getUserInfo() {

    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {print("Error getting user UID"); return}
    let userRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid)
    self.currentUser?.uid = uid

    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let usersDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            print(usersDict)
            for user in usersDict {
//                    guard let name = user.value(forKey: "name") else {print("Error getting user name"); return}
//                    guard let handle = user.value(forKey: "handle") else {print("Error getting user handle"); return}
//                    guard let gender = user.value(forKey: "gender") else {print("Error getting user gender"); return}
//                    guard let profilePicture = user.value(forKey: "profilePicture") else {print("Error getting user profilePicture"); return}
//                    print("\n\nName: \(name)\nHandle: \(handle)\nGender: \(gender)\nProfile Picture: \(profilePicture)\n\n")
            }
        }
    })
}
```

I get an error on each of the `user.value(forKey)` lines, stating "cannot call value of non-function type AnyObject".

If I `print(user.value)` inside the loop I get all of the current user's values back perfectly. I just can't specify them individually.

Answer (score 0):

it's easier than you think :-)

```
    let userRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)
```

Comment: Well that's the thing I'm trying to set the user's values, including their UID, with this function. They sign up for the app, and their values are stored in Firebase. Then when they enter the app, this function is called to set their user object with their info.

Comment: Saw your edit - it's the same approach that all 3 answers recommend, and it results in a crash.

Comment: Are you sure that the user is logged in, and that you have a valid value for uid?  You will get a crash if the child key is blank...

Comment: Yes, if I say `guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {print("Error getting user UID"); return}` inside the func and then `print("\nUID: \(uid)\n")`, it prints my UID.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another child to your userRef

```
guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }

let userRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid)
```

Comment: I tried that already but it resulted in a crash - not sure why, the crash takes me to the memory thread (?) screen.

Answer (score 0):

First get UID of the current user,

```
let currentUid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
```

then replace this database reference,

```
let userRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")
```

with this,

```
let userRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUid)
```

:-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do my load of the users info,

First, I created a NSObject Class called User...

```
 import UIKit

class User: NSObject {

// Add Whatever Child values of the user you have here
var email: String?
var nickname: String?

}
```

Then I called

```
func GetUserInfo() {

guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }

FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid)
.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

                let user = User()
                user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
                print(user.nickname!)

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Don't know if this helps or not..

Comment: I think that's generally what I'm trying, except you don't use a for loop, and you cast the snapshot as `[String: AnyObject]`. If I try to add a child for the uid, it crashed as soon as it gets to the `observeSingleEvent` line.